# How could I use references in post build task plugin of hudson

Tags: hudson, post-build

I have recognized that post build task plugin of hudson will provide an excellent service for development. The plugin allows us use java regex in log text, and the demo shows that we could pass the value matched in hudson log to the script.
Reference http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task. 
Thus, I have an idea that I could use pattern to match the log and "echo" different data according to matching result. However, in my experiment, the reference could not be recognized and pass into script. The hudson log as follow:

```
Match found for :PASSED: crawlEn(\d+) : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : echo %1 > g:\ELLUZZN\.hudson\jobs\test2.txt
[workspace] $ cmd /c call g:\apache-tomcat\temp\hudson373290022084813222.bat

g:\ELLUZZN\.hudson\jobs\HealthCheckTelekomSerbiaTest\workspace>echo   1>C:\Users\ELLUZZN\.hudson\jobs\test2.txt 

g:\ELLUZZN\.hudson\jobs\HealthCheckTelekomSerbiaTest\workspace>exit 0 
POST BUILD TASK : SUCCESS
END OF POST BUILD TASK : 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post-build-task doesn't give it results to running script as parameters as you expected according to the log provided.

I'm afraid you have to repeat regexp search in your postbuild script to receive that data.

Comment: But how could you explain the sample 2 in http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task?

Comment: If you mean "(\d+)", than it is not passed to your script, but it is used just for performing regexp comparison.